# Force shutdown of iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, shutdown

Is it possible to force the iPhone to shutdown (**programmatically**, of course)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not on an unjailbroken phone, no.

Answer (score 4):

Programatically, you can program a set of lego mindstorm to push the top button and the home button at the same time till it shutsdown ;-)

Comment: Heh, cute. Reminds me of ITAPPMONROBOT - http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/ITAPPMONROBOT.aspx

Answer (score 4):

As has already been answered: No.

In general, the answer to these questions is pretty easy. Ask yourself: "Could this feature be used to interfere with the operation of the iPhone *as a phone*?"

If the answer is yes, then no, you can't do it.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I suspected that might be the case, but was worth checking with the experts (ie you guys).